# Firebase Search and Update By Child's Child

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have following structure of firebase database:

```
-files
  |-LJsSTIfXcyzZy9N8RDV
     |-fileURL:"uploads/myfile.png"
  |-LJsSTIfXcyzxy9N8PqT
     |-fileURL:"uploads/myfile2.png"
```

Now i want to add a sibling of fileURL by using only value of fileURL.
So using value `'uploads/myfile.png'` i am trying to acheieve following:

```
-files
  |-LJsSTIfXcyzZy9N8RDV
     |-fileURL:"uploads/myfile.png"
     |-fileThumbURL:"uploads/myfileThumb.png"
  |-LJsSTIfXcyzxy9N8PqT
     |-fileURL:"uploads/myfile2.png"
```

I have tried following but it doesn't work.

```
fileURL = "uploads/myfile.png";
thumbURL = "uploads/myfileThumb.png";
admin.database().ref().child('files').orderByChild("fileURL").equalTo(fileURL ).once('value',function(snapshot){
            return snapshot.ref.child('fileThumbURL').set(thumbURL);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your code needs to handle this list, typically by using `snapshot.forEach()` to loop over the results. For example:

```
admin.database().ref().child('files').orderByChild("fileURL").equalTo(fileURL ).once('value',function(snapshot){
  snapshot.forEach(function(fileSnapshot) {
    fileSnapshot.child('fileThumbURL').set(thumbURL);
  });
});
```